# Copy task does not download artifact from artifactory

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have configured a Multi Job in Jenkins which contains 2 jobs `Build` and `Deploy` which executes `build.gradle` file.

`Build` job compiles a sample web application, creates a war file and publishes it to Artifactory.
`Deploy` job downloads the published job from the Artifactory and deploys it to the tomcat container.

The problem I am facing is, After the `Build` job has completed executing the Artifacts are published at the correct location in the Artifactory like `libs-alpha-local\com\myorg\myfile\1.0.1\myfile-1.0.1.war`.

But the Deploy job is failing to download the Artifact from the Artifactory. Below is the task I have for downloading the Artifact from the Artifactory.

```
configurations {
   deploy
}

dependencies {
   deploy group:"$project.group",
          name:"$project.name",version:"$project.version",ext: "war"
}

task downloadMyArchive(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.deploy
   into "$buildDir/download"
}
```

When I run the task, I get the message

`Skipping task ':downloadMyArchive' as it has no source files`

I want to use only gradle script for downloading the Artifactory and not use any plugins.

Comment: Did you specify any `repositories` where the artifacts can be found?

Comment: yes. I do specify respositories. `repositories {
        maven { url "${artifactoryUrl}/release" }
        maven { url "${artifactoryUrl}/alpha" }
        maven { url "${artifactoryUrl}/snapshot" }
}`

Comment: http://s18.postimg.org/64z7dzcfd/artifactorytree.png screenshot of Artifactory which shows the files in Artifactory.

Comment: What about permissions? Can this artifact be downloaded by the client?

Comment: yes, they can be downloaded.